# realloc() invalid pointer glibc error

Tags: pointers, glibc, realloc

I'm new to pointers and `realloc`.  I know what is going wrong, but I don't know how to solve it.

I create a struct with an array of pointers:

```
struct DB_SLOT
{
    MYSQL *MYSQL_Connection[10];
    char  *DB_NAME_Connection[10];
};
struct DB_SLOT DB_Conn_SLOT;
```

I allocate memory with `realloc` in a loop and (this is where it is getting wrong) I print the address of pointer 2 on the screens.

If I then try to `realloc` the same amount of memory (just for test purposes). it gives a `glibc` invalid pointer. Before `realloc` I print the address of pointer 2 again and it is not the same.

The code for this:

```
int MallocLoop;

for (MallocLoop = 0;MallocLoop < 10;MallocLoop++)
{
    DB_Conn_SLOT.MYSQL_Connection[MallocLoop] = realloc(DB_Conn_SLOT.MYSQL_Connection[MallocLoop],(sizeof(MYSQL)));
    DB_Conn_SLOT.DB_NAME_Connection[MallocLoop]=realloc(DB_Conn_SLOT.DB_NAME_Connection[MallocLoop],(sizeof(char)));
    if (MallocLoop == 2)
    {   
        printf("pointer  1 %d \n",DB_Conn_SLOT.DB_NAME_Connection[MallocLoop]);
    }
    DB_Conn_SLOT.DB_NAME_Connection[MallocLoop] ="\0";
}
MallocLoop = 2;
printf("pointer  2 %d \n",DB_Conn_SLOT.DB_NAME_Connection[MallocLoop]);
DB_Conn_SLOT.DB_NAME_Connection[MallocLoop] = realloc(DB_Conn_SLOT.DB_NAME_Connection[MallocLoop], (sizeof(char)));
```

The result of printing the address of the pointer results in 2 different addresses. How do i solve this??

Answer (score 0):

You have the following two lines:

```
DB_Conn_SLOT.DB_NAME_Connection[MallocLoop]=realloc(...); ...
DB_Conn_SLOT.DB_NAME_Connection[MallocLoop] ="\0";
```

Let's simplify this to:

```
p = realloc(...);
p = "\0";
```

The first line makes `p` point at dynamically allocated memory block. The second line *leaks* that memory (you no longer have a pointer to it), and makes `p` point to a block of memory inside the `.data` section.

When you loop again, and pass the `.data` pointer to `realloc`, it correctly complains: it is not valid to pass non-dynamically allocated memory to `realloc`.

What you *probably* wanted to do was this:

```
p = realloc(...);
p[0] = '\0';
```

That makes `p` point to a dynamically allocated memory block, and makes that block be an empty string.